# Django social auth disable for admin

Tags: django, python-social-auth

In python social auth library:

I am making a social auth for my django project. I want to disable social auth for admin.
how it works by default:

1. social auth url is visited and permissions granted
2. new `Python Social Auth › User social auths` object is created for Admin
3. this social account logs in admin

How I want it to work:

1. social auth url is visited and permissions granted
2. new `Python Social Auth › User social auths` object is created along with new regular user, as if admin was not logged in
3. this social account logs in a regular user

Is there an elegant way of doing this? Overriding the least amount of pipeline functions as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to directly forbid `admin` users from using the social authentication process, for that you need a custom function in the pipeline that would raise [`AuthForbidden`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1eadf8fa7b13a79363e4fa51ce06e0ae1cc3ca63/social_core/exceptions.py#L102) if the user is an admin.

This function should be after the [`social_user`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1eadf8fa7b13a79363e4fa51ce06e0ae1cc3ca63/social_core/pipeline/__init__.py#L18) step to ensure that already associated accounts are identified. The code for that function should be something simple like:

```
def disable_admin(backend, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if user and user.is_admin:
        raise AuthForbidden(backend)
```

More docs about extending the pipeline [here](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline).